# Removing Thinktcture.IdentityModel.EmbeddedSts

Tags: asp.net, .net, nuget

I installed the NuGet package 'EmbeddedSTS' to test a proof of concept. It worked well and I was happy with the package.

I decided to remove the package. However, when I removed the EmbeddedSTS package and built my solution, I got the following error:

> The pre-application start initialization method Start on type
>   Thinktecture.IdentityModel.EmbeddedSts.EmbeddedStstConfiguration threw
>   and     exception with the following error message: ID7027 Could not
>   load the identity    configuration because no 
>   configuration section was found.

Am I missing a step to completely remove the `EmbeddedSTS` package?

When I check the installed packages on the solution, `EmbeddedSTS` is not there.

My question is NOT how to fix the error message; its how to remove the `EmbededSTS` from Visual Solution/ Solution

Many Thanks!

Comment: How you removed `EmbeddedSTS` package? add steps!

Comment: I shelved all my changes in TFS.

Comment: Refer here: [Removing a Package](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. There is a EmbeddedSTS DLL in the bin which is fired up each time you start debugging. By removing this DLL I was able to get my solution to build again.